# pandas: selecting rows in a specific time window

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset of samples covering multiple days, all with a timestamp.
I want to select rows within a specific time window. E.g. all rows that were generated between 1pm and 3 pm every day.

This is a sample of my data in a pandas dataframe:

```
22           22  2018-04-12T20:14:23Z  2018-04-12T21:14:23Z      0  6370.1   
23           23  2018-04-12T21:14:23Z  2018-04-12T21:14:23Z      0  6368.8   
24           24  2018-04-12T22:14:22Z  2018-04-13T01:14:23Z      0  6367.4   
25           25  2018-04-12T23:14:22Z  2018-04-13T01:14:23Z      0  6365.8   
26           26  2018-04-13T00:14:22Z  2018-04-13T01:14:23Z      0  6364.4   
27           27  2018-04-13T01:14:22Z  2018-04-13T01:14:23Z      0  6362.7   
28           28  2018-04-13T02:14:22Z  2018-04-13T05:14:22Z      0  6361.0   
29           29  2018-04-13T03:14:22Z  2018-04-13T05:14:22Z      0  6359.3   
..          ...                   ...                   ...    ...     ...   
562         562  2018-05-05T08:13:21Z  2018-05-05T09:13:21Z      0  6300.9   
563         563  2018-05-05T09:13:21Z  2018-05-05T09:13:21Z      0  6300.7   
564         564  2018-05-05T10:13:14Z  2018-05-05T13:13:14Z      0  6300.2   
565         565  2018-05-05T11:13:14Z  2018-05-05T13:13:14Z      0  6299.9   
566         566  2018-05-05T12:13:14Z  2018-05-05T13:13:14Z      0  6299.6
```

How do I achieve that? I need to ignore the date and just evaluate the time component. I could traverse the dataframe in a loop and evaluate the date time in that way, but there must be a more simple way to do that..

I converted the messageDate which was read a a string to a dateTime by

```
df["messageDate"]=pd.to_datetime(df["messageDate"])
```

But after that I got stuck on how to filter on time only.

Any input appreciated.

Comment: can you provide your sample data set with header

Comment: IN[31]: df.columns
Out[31]: 
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'messageDate', 'receivedDate', 'error', 'P1', 'type',
       'T1', 'T2'],
      dtype='object')

The messageDate columns is now of the type dateTime64

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`datetime` columns have `DatetimeProperties` object, from which you can extract `datetime.time` and filter on it:

```
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        '2018-04-12T12:00:00Z', '2018-04-12T14:00:00Z','2018-04-12T20:00:00Z',
        '2018-04-13T12:00:00Z', '2018-04-13T14:00:00Z', '2018-04-13T20:00:00Z'
    ], 
    columns=['messageDate']
)
df
            messageDate
# 0 2018-04-12 12:00:00
# 1 2018-04-12 14:00:00
# 2 2018-04-12 20:00:00
# 3 2018-04-13 12:00:00
# 4 2018-04-13 14:00:00
# 5 2018-04-13 20:00:00

df["messageDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["messageDate"])
time_mask = (df['messageDate'].dt.hour >= 13) & \
            (df['messageDate'].dt.hour <= 15)

df[time_mask]
#           messageDate
# 1 2018-04-12 14:00:00
# 4 2018-04-13 14:00:00
```

Comment: time_mask = (df['messageDate'].dt.time >= tm.datetime.time(13)) & \
            (df['messageDate'].dt.time <= tm.datetime.time(15))
#
#

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-33-e34767fc753a>", line 1, in <module>
    time_mask = (df['messageDate'].dt.time >= tm.datetime.time(13)) &             (df['messageDate'].dt.time <= tm.datetime.time(15))
#
#
TypeError: descriptor 'time' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'

Doesn't seem to like it. (I imported date time as tm)

Comment: @HansvanSchaick `datetime` is `datetime` module, not `datetime.datetime`. I will add import statement to make that clear

Comment: Got it! You pointed me in the right direction:

time_mask = (df['messageDate'].dt.hour >= 13) & (df['messageDate'].dt.hour <= 15)

Sorry for the clumsy editing...

Comment: This is a great answer. I love one-liners. I knew this could be done, but couldn't find it anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I hope the code is self explanatory. You can always ask questions.

```
import pandas as pd

#   Prepping data for example
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=7, freq='H')
data = {'A' : range(7)}
df = pd.DataFrame(index = dates, data = data)
print df
#                      A
# 2018-01-01 00:00:00  0
# 2018-01-01 01:00:00  1
# 2018-01-01 02:00:00  2
# 2018-01-01 03:00:00  3
# 2018-01-01 04:00:00  4
# 2018-01-01 05:00:00  5
# 2018-01-01 06:00:00  6

#   Creating a mask to filter the value we with to have or not.
#   Here, we use df.index because the index is our datetime.
#   If the datetime is a column, you can always say df['column_name']
mask = (df.index > '2018-1-1 01:00:00') & (df.index < '2018-1-1 05:00:00')
print mask
# [False False  True  True  True False False]

df_with_good_dates = df.loc[mask]
print df_with_good_dates
#                      A
# 2018-01-01 02:00:00  2
# 2018-01-01 03:00:00  3
# 2018-01-01 04:00:00  4
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. With dates thats fine. I need to filter on the the time though. I have 24 measurements a day. I only want to look at midnight for example of every day. But not exact, because the sample can be generated at a random time within each hour.

Comment: Have you looked at [between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) ?

Comment: @HansvanSchaick I updated my answer to fit your criteria. This answer is still the best way to proceed in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
df=df[(df["messageDate"].apply(lambda x : x.hour)>13) & (df["messageDate"].apply(lambda x : x.hour)<15)]
```

You can use x.minute, x.second similarly.

Answer (score 0):

try this after ensuring messageDate is indeed datetime format as you have done

```
df.set_index('messageDate',inplace=True)
choseInd = [ind for ind in df.index if (ind.hour>=13)&(ind.hour<=15)]
df_select = df.loc[choseInd]
```

you can do the same, even without making the datetime column as an index, as the answer with apply: lambda shows

it just makes your dataframe 'better looking'  if the datetime is your index rather than numerical one.